# How can I make an RPM counter for a diesel motor with an Arduino?

Tags: gauge

I'm new to Arduinos and would like to make an RPM meter or if possible a RPM wave converter.

I get an RPM signal from the engine via pin 9 from OBD connector,  but the signal is quite dirty and a random wave. In order for my RPM gauge to work, it needs a square wave.

I have a recording of the signal. Could you help me figure this out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  You'll find you get the best out of EE.SE by posting quite a lot of detail with specific questions you need help with.  Then people have something concrete to help you with, knowing exactly what problems you're trying to solve.  Why not edit in more of your detail (like your sample wave) and what your difficulty is.

Comment: Use pin 5 (signal ground) for ground and pin 9 for RPM.  Some of the noise may be coming from the use of pin 4 (chassis ground.)  Other than that, it looks like you are getting two pulses per rotation.

Comment: What are you using as an oscilloscope?  Is the coupling set to AC or DC?

Comment: Quite likely: Modest smoothing to remove very fast changes and then a Schmitt trigger with suitable thresholds. You have two pulses which could be dealt with to produce only one (monostable?) or halve count.

Comment: As Russel says, some modest smoothing would probably help. Then why not try a monostable? A 555 timer like this https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/555-timer-monostable-circuit/ .  Use their calculator to set the output pulse width so that it is longer than the furthest apart (low RPM) double pulses get and narrower then the closest the pair get at high RPM. If this proves impossible than generate two narrow pulses and divide by 2!

Comment: Sorry that i did not provided all de infos from the start . My problem is that i have swapped the engine in my old nissan patrol that has a rpm gauge that only accepts  square waves . I have swapped the engine with a bmw m57 that had a CAN bus instrument cluster. I have found that bmw put also a rpm signal on pin9 in the obd connectir from were i have also pulled the graph